# How to use python readlines method in random order

Tags: python

How can one use the `readlines()` method to read a file in a random shuffled manner i.e. `random.shuffle()`

```
file = open(filename)
data = file.readlines()           
file_length =  len(data)
```

Comment: You can't do that in that order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get them into a list with `lines = file.readlines()`, and then `random.shuffle(lines)` that list (import `random` module).

Answer (score 2):

You can store the entire file as a list of lines with:

```
f = open(filename)
data = f.read() # the whole file in one string
lines = data.split('\n')
```

Then use random to access lines.